# Fastify Plugin Performance

Tags: node.js, fastify

I created a plugin for simple queries with caching and connection pooling. When i respond with that plugin (function), response is slower than before. So i wonder if I got the plugin thing wrong. Is this a correct use or am I making a mistake somewhere?

db.js

```
const fp = require('fastify-plugin')

const oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
oracledb.autoCommit = true;

module.exports = fp(async function (fastify, opts) {
  fastify.decorate('simpleSelectWithCache', async function (key, ttl, sql) {
      let cached = await fastify.cache.get(key);
    if (cached) {
        console.log('Cached:', cached.item);
        return cached.item;
      } else {
        let connection;
        try {
          connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
          const data = await connection.execute(sql);
          fastify.cache.set(key, data.rows, ttl);
          console.log('Real:', data.rows);
          return data.rows;
          // oracledb.getPool()._logStats(); // show pool statistics.  _enableStats must be true
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(err);
        } finally {
          if (connection) await connection.close();
        }
      }
  })
})
```

api.js

```
module.exports = async function (fastify, opts) {
  fastify.get(
    '/cached',
    {
      schema: {
        description: 'Shared Api',
        tags: ['Shared'],
      },
    },
    async function (req, reply) {
      const data = await fastify.simpleSelectWithCache('shared-cached', 60*1000, 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id < 50')
      reply.send(data);
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a correct use or am I making a mistake somewhere?

The connection is a heavy operation and, for every query, a new connection (aka a new socket) is created between your server and DB.

To optimize your plugin you need to create the connection pool at start:

```js
module.exports = fp(async function (fastify, opts) {
  await oracledb.createPool({
    user: opts.user,
    password: opts.password,
    connectString: opts.connectString
  })

  fastify.decorate('simpleSelectWithCache', async function (key, ttl, sql) {
    const cached = await fastify.cache.get(key)
    if (cached) {
      console.log('Cached:', cached.item)
      return cached.item
    } else {
      let connection
      try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection()
        const data = await connection.execute(sql)
        fastify.cache.set(key, data.rows, ttl)
        console.log('Real:', data.rows)
        return data.rows
        // oracledb.getPool()._logStats(); // show pool statistics.  _enableStats must be true
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      } finally {
        if (connection) await connection.close()
      }
    }
  })

  fastify.addHook('onClose', (instance, done) => {
    oracledb.getPool().close(10)
      .then(done)
      .catch(done)
  })
})


// then register your plugin
fastify.register(myOraclePlugin, {
  user: 'ora'
  password: '1234',
  connectString: 'foo'
})
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't say it. I create connection pooling at startup as min-max 10. oracledb.getConnection() gets connection from pool. Pooling and caching is really effective. I just wonder about plugin usage. There are docs but community is weak. This kind of questions is good for all future users.